# VBA to Check Values in Exactly Same Cell in Different Work Book Then Copy Source Values to Certain Cells in Destination Work Book

Tags: excel, vba, match, copy-paste

I just started learning VBA since last week because my department does repetitive excel works.

One of job that really frustrates me is that

**1. I make a certain excel form and give to all other departments in the company and collect back the workbook.**
lets say : column A has project codes and column B has values for each project codes

**2. Then I match all columns in the source workbook is exact match of the destination workbook.(incl. project codes)**
checking to see if other departments altered my original workbook.

**3. If they all matches then I copy and paste numbers from The source work book to the destination workbook.**
checking if A1~A200 Project codes in destination workbook have same project codes in A1~A200 source workbook and if they match then return B1 value from the source to the destination workbook.

I thought about using index match or vlookup but I have about 30sheets+ and around 100+ entries for each sheet.

Please help!

Comment: easy enough but will need some example data etc.

Comment: Please share a bit more which formulas you tried and which part isn't working as intended.